# What is the utility of the : command in shell scripting, given that it explicitly does nothing?

Tags: shell, shell-script

In the answer to [this question about comments in shell scripting](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/37411/multiline-shell-script-comments-how-does-this-work), it is indicated that the `:` is a null command that explicitly does nothing (but is not to be used for comments).

What would be the utility of a command that does absolutely nothing?

Comment: See also [What purpose does the colon built-in serve](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31673/what-purpose-does-the-colon-builtin-serve).

Comment: See also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224878/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-colon-gnu-bash-builtin) which has an even better answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3224910/712765), namely that `:` is required to be a built-in, while `true` is not, which affects the scope of variables

Comment: It explicitly does nothing *gracefully*.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I typically use `true` in loops; I think it's more clear:

```
while true; do
    ...
done
```

The one place I've found that `:` is really handy is in case statements, if you need to match something but don't want to actually do anything.  For example:

```
case $answer in
    ([Yy]*) : ok ;;
    (*)     echo "stop."; exit 1 ;;
esac
```

Comment: I agree.  `true` for a condition, `:` for a NOP.

Comment: bash accepts `case a in a ) ;; esac`. Are there some shells which don't accept this?

Comment: @Kaz:  According to the [POSIX shell grammar](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_10), `case ${var} in value);; *) do_something;; esac` is acceptable.  The `:` command is not needed for empty cases.

Comment: The part about using `true` seems like a non-sequitur without reading some of the other answers first.

Comment: Another place `:` is handy is when `:=` to assign shell variables, like `: ${FOO:=bar}`

Answer (score 13):

Originally, it was used to determine that it was a Bourne shell program, as opposed to C compiled program.  This was before shebang and multiple scripting languages (csh, perl).  You can still run a script starting with just `:`:

```
$ echo : > /tmp/xyzzy
$ chmod +x /tmp/xyzzy
$ ./xyzzy
```

It will generally run the script against `$SHELL` (or `/bin/sh`).

Since then, the main use is to evaluate the arguments.  I still use:

```
: ${EDITOR:=vim}
```

to set a default value in a script.

Answer (score 10):

`:` is useful for writing loops that must be terminated from within.

```
while :
do
    ...stuff...
done
```

This will run forever unless `break` or `exit` is called, or the shell receives a terminating signal.

Comment: I feel that `while true; do ...; done` communicates intentions to the reader better than `while :; do ...; done`

Answer (score 10):

When you want an "unless" statement in shell scripting, you either use a "not" condition, which can look goofy for some of the tests, or you use ':' in the true-clause, with real code in the false-clause.

```
if [ some-exotic-condition ]
then
    :
else
    # Real code here
fi
```

The "exotic condition" could be something you don't want to negate, or that's just a lot clearer if you don't use "negative logic".

Comment: It also shows up in scripts generated by `autoconf` because it's much easier to add a default `:` for empty branches than it is to figure out how to reverse the condition.

Comment: I can't see how sticking in a `!` in front of `[ some-exotic-condition ]` is goofy, but a superfluous `: else` after it is not goofy.

Comment: @Kaz has a good point.  Let's keep in mind that coming up with exotic conditions is difficult at best.  If you have to negate all of it, that's one thing, but it might just make the condition less clear. Does a '!' negate the whole condition, or just the first term?  Best to have a ':' true clause sometimes.

Comment: The `!` token negates an entire command pipe element.  `while ! grep ... ; do ... done`  or `if ! [ ... ] ; then ... fi`. It's basically external to the `test/[]` syntax.  See: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_02

Answer (score 8):

I've only ever used this in addition to the # character for temporarily commenting out a line, in a situation in which commenting out the line produces a syntax error, due to a defect in the shell grammar of not allowing an empty sequence of commands:

```
if condition ; then
    :# temporarily commented out command
fi
```

Without the : we have a missing command sequence, which is a syntax error.

Answer (score 5):

There are two cases where I find `:` useful:

### Default variable assignments

```
#!/bin/sh

# set VAR to "default value" if not already set in the environment
: "${VAR=default value}"

# print the value of the VAR variable.  Note that POSIX says the behavior
# of echo is implementation defined if the first argument is '-n' or if any
# argument contains a '\', so use printf instead of echo.
printf '%s\n' "VAR=${VAR}"
```

This is a convenient way to allow users of your shell script to override a setting without editing the script.  (However, [command-line arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6310937/712605) are better because you don't run the risk of unexpected behavior if the user coincidentally has the variable you use in their exported environment.)  Here's how the user would override the setting:

```
VAR="other value" ./script
```

The `${VAR=value}` syntax says to set `VAR` to `value` if `VAR` isn't already set, then expand to the value of the variable.  Since we don't care about the value of the variable just yet, it is passed as an argument to the no-op command `:` to throw it away.

Even though `:` is a no-op command, expansion is performed by the shell (not the `:` command!) before running the `:` command so the variable assignment still occurs (if applicable).

It would also be acceptable to use `true` or some other command instead of `:`, but the code becomes harder to read because the intention is less clear.

The following script would also work:

```
#!/bin/sh

# print the value of the VAR variable.  Note that POSIX says the behavior
# of echo is implementation defined if the first argument is '-n' or if any
# argument contains a '\', so use printf instead of echo.
printf '%s\n' "VAR=${VAR=default value}"
```

But the above is much harder to maintain.  If a line using `${VAR}` is added above that `printf` line, the default assignment expansion has to be moved.  If the developer forgets to move that assignment, a bug is introduced.

### Something to put in an empty conditional block

Empty conditional blocks should generally be avoided, but they're sometimes useful:

```
if some_condition; then
    # todo:  implement this block of code; for now do nothing.
    # the colon below is a no-op to prevent syntax errors
    :
fi
```

Some people argue that having an empty true `if` block can make code easier to read than negating the test.  For example:

```
if [ -f foo ] && bar || baz; then
    :
else
    do_something_here
fi
```

is arguably easier to read than:

```
if ! [ -f foo ] || ! bar && ! baz; then
    do_something_here
fi
```

However I believe there are a few alternative approaches that are better than an empty true block:

1. Put the condition in a function:

   ```
   exotic_condition() { [ -f foo ] && bar || baz; }

   if ! exotic_condition; then
       do_something_here
   fi
   ```
2. Put the condition inside curly braces (or parentheses, but parentheses spawn a subshell process and any changes made to the environment inside the subshell won't be visible outside the subshell) before negating:

   ```
   if ! { [ -f foo ] && bar || baz; } then
       do_something_here
   fi
   ```
3. Use `||` instead of `if`:

   ```
   [ -f foo ] && bar || baz || {
       do_something_here
   }
   ```

   I prefer this approach when the reaction is a simple one-liner, such as asserting conditions:

   ```
   log() { printf '%s\n' "$*"; }
   error() { log "ERROR: $*" >&2; }
   fatal() { error "$@"; exit 1; }

   [ -f foo ] && bar || baz || fatal "condition not met"
   ```

Answer (score 2):

In the old pre-bourne shell in ancient versions of UNIX, the `:` command was originally intended for specifying labels for `goto` (it was a separate command which winds the input to where the label is found, so labels couldn't be a separate syntax that the shell knows about. `if` was also a separate command.) It soon became used for comments, before there was a comment syntax (`#` was used for backspace) and these days is around for compatibility as much as anything.

Answer (score 1):

The ":" shell command exists because in the original v1 shell, the Thompson shell, ":" introduced a label that was potentially the target of a `goto` command.

The Wikipedia Thompson shell article notes that:

> The shell's design was intentionally minimalistic; even the if and
>   goto statements, essential for control of program flow, were
>   implemented as separate commands.

[V1 Unix source](https://github.com/jserv/unix-v1) contains that of a [standalone goto command](https://github.com/jserv/unix-v1/blob/master/src/cmd/goto.c). It's got a `main()` function making it a standalone program. It appears to read through stdin until it finds a ":" character, then it reads zero or more ASCII space characters, then the label. If that's the label it currently looks for, it does an `lseek()` on stdin.

My other answer to this question is incorrect. I'm not deleting it because it contains a common use of ":" in the shell.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to using it as a statement that does nothing, you can use it to comment out single statements by turning them into arguments for :.

Comment: It won't be exactly a comment since `: echo write this line > myfile` will still create an empty file.

Comment: As explained in the link in the question, `:` is *NOT* an adequate commenting mechanism.