# What if I don't want to do anything in a if-then block but something in its else block?

Tags: shell

```
#intro
if [ -n "$1" ]
    then
        echo 666
    else
        echo 555
fi
exit;
```

Actually I do want to `echo 555` while I don't want to do anything in the first block, what should I do? I noticed that I can't just remove `echo 666`.

Comment: use `true` or `:` (instead of echo 666)

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/37473/what-is-the-utility-of-the-command-in-shell-scripting-given-that-it-explicitl

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just using [no-op](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_16):

```
if [ -n "$1" ]; then
  :
else
  echo 555
fi
exit
```

or invert the logic:

```
if [ -z "$1" ]; then
  echo 555
fi
exit
```

Answer (score 3):

```
[ -n "$1" ] && echo "666"  <= For if part
[ -n "$1" ] || echo "555"  <= For else part
```

Answer (score 3):

You can invert an if statement by using `!` (this is called the 'not' operator, which means take the opposite of the result) inside the conditional. So that `[ -n "$1" ]` becomes:`[ ! -n "$1" ]`, which is the same as the `else` section.

It's also valid to use the `-z` option instead of `-n` which is logically inverse to `-n`, but as a general rule the `!` will always match whatever the else section would match.